# Combinations of Columns based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have 370 columns and I have to generate unique combinations of 2, 3 and 4 columns. However, there is a condition that I need to apply on these on combinations (see table below first and condition that I need apply below)

```
My columns are named in this fashion 
Column 1 Name :   'Real'
Column 2 Name :   'Real_lag1'
Column 3 Name :   'Real_lag2'
Column 4 Name :   'Real_lag3'
Column 5 Name :   'Real_lag4'
Column 6 Name :   'Normal'
Column 7 Name :   'Normal_chng'
Column 9 Name :   'Normal_diff'
Column 10 Name :  'Andi_diff'
Column 11 Name :  'Vari_lag1'
Column 12 Name :  'Teo_diff'
Column 13 Name :  'Lan_diff'
.
.
.
.
```

Essentially I have 24 unique values which have been lagged, transformed into a total of 370 variables (as shown above) etc. like for example you can see _lag _chng, _diff are all transformations of 24 unique columns (like 'Real','Normal', 'Andi', 'Vari', 'Teo, 'Lan' etc)

I want to generate unique combinations of these 370 variables however only one variable can come from the parent variable.

For example, 'Real' and 'Real_lag1' can NOT appear in the a combination together.

If try to run all the combinations (using 370) there are 776,741,925 combinations in total (2 at a time, 3 at a time, 4 at a time) and apply a condition on this it will take a lot of time to run this

Comment: This looks like a combination of a mathematical and a coding problem. To generate the possible combinations, you might want to have a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Based on 24 unique groups, combine 2/3/4 elements.

Comment: Yeah. I think a way to do this is to group the 370 variables under parent variable) and then choose one from each parent variable. 
But how I do go about doing this?

Comment: For 2 parents each: ```parents2 = list(itertools.combinations(np.arange(24),2))```. This creates a list of parent-combinations. Adapt for 3/4 parents accordingly. Then for every pair/triple/quadruple of parents, go through all combinations in each group. ```itertools``` is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df`
1. get list of all column names

```
col_names = df.columns
```

2. separate parents from child names (I'm very open to suggestions for better looking code!)

```
tmp = [col.split('_') for col in col_names]

parent_child = {}
for col in tmp:
    if len(col)>1:
        if col[0] not in parent_child.keys():
            parent_child[col[0]] = [col[0]]
        if (col[0] in parent_child.keys()) and (col[1] not in parent_child.values()):
            parent_child[col[0]].append(col[1])
    else:
        parent_child[col[0]] = [col[0]]

>> parent_child
{'Andi': ['Andi', 'diff'],
 'Lan': ['Lan', 'diff'],
 'Normal': ['Normal', 'chng', 'diff'],
 'Real': ['Real', 'lag1', 'lag2', 'lag3', 'lag4'],
 'Teo': ['Teo', 'diff'],
 'Vari': ['Vari', 'lag1']}
```

I added the parent name to the children's list, since the stand-alone parent name is also an option, according to your example.
3. Get all combinations of 2 parents (adapt accordingly for 3 or 4 parents)

```
comb2 = list(itertools.combinations(list(parent_child.keys()),2)
comb2 
('Real', 'Normal')
('Real', 'Andi')
('Real', 'Vari')
...
('Andi', 'Lan')
('Vari', 'Teo')
('Vari', 'Lan')
('Teo', 'Lan')
```

4. Generate all combinations of parents:

```
combinations = []
for p in comb2:
    for v1 in parent_child[p[0]]:
        for v2 in parent_child[p[1]]:
            print(v1, p[0], v2, p[1])
            if v1 == p[0]:
                name1 = p[0]
            else:
                name1 = str(p[0]+'_'+v1)
            if v2 == p[1]:
                name2 = p[1]
            else:
                name2 = str(p[1]+'_'+v2)
            combinations.append((name1,name2))
>> combinations
[('Real', 'Normal'),
 ('Real', 'Normal_chng'),
 ('Real', 'Normal_diff'),
 ('Real_lag1', 'Normal'),
 ('Real_lag1', 'Normal_chng'),
 ('Real_lag1', 'Normal_diff'),
 ('Real_lag2', 'Normal'),
 ('Real_lag2', 'Normal_chng'),
 ('Real_lag2', 'Normal_diff'),
 ('Real_lag3', 'Normal'),
...
('Vari', 'Lan'),
 ('Vari', 'Lan_diff'),
 ('Vari_lag1', 'Lan'),
 ('Vari_lag1', 'Lan_diff'),
 ('Teo', 'Lan'),
 ('Teo', 'Lan_diff'),
 ('Teo_diff', 'Lan'),
 ('Teo_diff', 'Lan_diff')]
```

Comment: What is Parent2 here? dont think it is defined here? Is it comb2

Comment: Thanks man, it works but the run-time is still relatively high if i put the combos of 2 variables in a dataframe. Any suggestions to decrease runtime

Comment: the whole point of me doing this is to run multiple mutlivariate regressions on these 370 variables. Do you think it is effecient like this to run combinations and from these run regressions for these combinations

Comment: The slowest part is probably the calculations of the combinations. The sheer amount of combinations will make it rather slow, in general. If you just check the number of combinations for 2 variables, you'll see it's huge. I'm afraid, there isn't much you can do to speed this up, since it's not a convex search problem. Any experts on (mathematical) optimization might be of better help. Maybe check out [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/) or [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).